# C++ simple hooks and hiding command prompt

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I am new to C++ and have just learned about hooks so I have a C++ program which runs a function when a KeyEvent occurs:

```
LRESULT WINAPI KeyEvent(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{  
  //Do C++ stuff
}
```

This is my only hook so far.

However I want to hide the command prompt which pops up when executing my code.

I was told I can use this snippet to hide it:

```
HWND Stealth;
AllocConsole();
Stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
ShowWindow(Stealth,0);
```

However if I place it in the hook it will not hide the prompt until a key is pressed (not ideal) and if I place it above the hook (near top of program) I get an error...

So my question is, is there any other types of hooks which I can place the snippet in to hide the command prompt once program is ran? -Or is there any other way like my snippet to hide command prompts which I can use?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Hooks are not a C++ thing (the language standard don't mention them) but a WINAPI thing. If you coded with Qt (which would make you code portably for Windows, Linux, MacOSX, ...) you won't use hooks (but Qt signal and slot mechanism).

Comment: if you don't need a console, why not make the program `Win32` and just don't create any window?

Comment: And how would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Change your project settings to build a "GUI" application (this changes a few linker options), and provide a [WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) entry point instead of main. That way there will be no console window.

Comment: Won't this on the contrary make the software a GUI one?

Comment: There will be some changes, like you won't have stdin/stdout/stderr anymore (because there is no console anymore), and it won't open a console window if you run it via the GUI shell. Other than that, your program will not be a "GUI" program unless you create a GUI.

Comment: Do you know how I can change project settings in Dev C++?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the WM_CREATE msg to do what you want. And inside it call:

```
if(MSG == WM_CREATE)
  ShowWindow( GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE );
```

That might work for you, and if you need the console again just change SW_HIDE to SW_SHOW.

Usually you would use a switch statement for the message type.